# Android: setting an alarm clock from a broadcast receiver only works once

Tags: android, clock, alarm

I'm making an android app to be used to help recover a lost phone. The app uses a Service that is constantly running and when a text message (SMS) is received by the phone, a BroadcastReceiver's (already registered in the service)  onReceive() event is triggered. The functionality that I want is that the BroadcastReceiver be able to make the phone produce a loud noise even if the phone was on silent. The most logical way I can think of doing this is to use and alarm clock set one minute from the current time.

This is the code I'm currently using inside of the broadcast receiver:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Polo!");
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1);
context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
```

Fortunately, this code works, but it only ever works once. But that I mean, the first time this code is run, the phone's flow is interrupted and the clock app is opened with a new alarm set. When you attempt to do this again, the clock app is opened, but no alarm is set. I have to restart my phone to get this to work again.

From what I can tell, the issue has to do with the clock app and I need to restart the clock app to get my service to work. This is a really sketchy solution, but I don't know what else to do.

Any recommendations?

Comment: you could look at it https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html it's maybe more suitable for what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to develop your own Alarm screen and re-set the alarm while onCreate. 
Like that, your app will continuously ring up.

for that : 
initialise a WakefulBroadcastReceiver

manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>
```

AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
        alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Polo!");
        alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1);
        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

MyAlarm.java :

```
public class MyAlarm extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // doing UI stuff
        AlarmUtil.setAlarm(this);
    }
}
```

AlarmUtil.java

```
 public class AlarmUtil {
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     public static void setAlarm(Context context){
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         int requestCode = 1234;
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60 * 1000, pi);    
         }
         else{
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60 * 1000, pi);
         }  
   }
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that instead of utilizing the default clock app, I, essentially, just make my own simple version that solely exists to turn off the alarm?